# Using jQuery with Canvas not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

I'm trying to put a picture in the center of a canvas using jQuery. First I did it without jQuery:

```
function initCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
    canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
    canvas.style.backgroundColor = CANVAS_COLOR; // black color
    return canvas;
}

function drawEarth(ctx) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = EARTH_PNG;
    img.addEventListener("load", function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, CANVAS_X - EARTH_X, CANVAS_Y - EARTH_Y, EARTH_WIDTH,     EARTH_HEIGHT);
    });
}

function render() {
    var canvas = initCanvas();
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    drawEarth(ctx);
}

// init function
(function () {
    render();
})();
```

and it worked. Then I modified the `initCanvas()` function:

```
function initCanvas(){
    var canvas = $("#canvas");
    canvas.height(CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    canvas.width(CANVAS_WIDTH);
    canvas.css({"background-color": CANVAS_COLOR}); // black color
    return canvas[0];
}
```

it did not draw the picture. The background was black though. I check the [document](http://api.jquery.com/css/) it says *For example,  `$( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "green" )` is equivalent to `document.getElementById( "mydiv" ).style.color = "green"`.* So I don't know what's wrong here. Anyone can help? Thanks!

Thanks to comment below I changed the init code after using jQuery:

```
$(function (){
    render();
});
```

but it's still not working.

Comment: Per your own comment, isn't your use of the css function wrong?

Comment: I can either use it with an object or with 2 parameters. I tried both but neither of them worked.

Comment: oh, didn't see that in the docs and haven't used jquery in a while, it just jumped out at me.  Any errors on the console with this code?

Comment: No errors. I also put a break point to check `canvas.getContext("2d")` and it is the normal object, not undefined or something else.

Comment: You should know that the jquery functions should be used after document.ready move your code (with jquery into) $(function(){ . . . }); and test.

Comment: It seems to work for me.  Can you look at this jsfiddle and tell me what is different from your code? https://jsfiddle.net/oLf932z6/

Comment: Ok thanks for the patient. After trying your solution I locate the problem is the `ctx.drawImage()`. With the parameters you used, it shows the picture. However with the parameters I was using, which was working without jQuery, it would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do canvas width/height by `.css()` .But `context.canvas.width/height` is working with jquery .You should change a little **initCanvas and render** function.

```
function render() {
    var canvas = initCanvas();    
    drawEarth(canvas);
}

function initCanvas() {
    var c = $("#canvas");
    var ctx = c[0].getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
    ctx.canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
    c.css({"background-color": CANVAS_COLOR}); // black color
    return ctx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code mate. If you try by replacing the values of canvas_height,width and color on a simple div and you will get the desired output.

```
function initCanvas(){
$('#abc').css('width',CANVAS_HEIGHT);
$('#abc').css('height',CANVAS_WIDTH);
$('#abc').css('background-color',CANVAS_COLOR);
return canvas[0];
}
```